# Using canvas field to paint on a custom control

Tags: delphi

This code generates an error:

---

### Debugger Exception Notification

### Project Project3.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x7757e12c: write of address 0x00000014'.

```
if Fowner_draw then
   begin
   canvas.CopyRect(ClientRect, FOD_canvas, ClientRect);
   end
```

I found the solution by deleting pasteBmp.free; line from the code below. It seems like each time copyRect is called the value of FOD_canvas field is assigned again.

```
procedure Tncrtile.copy_rect(Cimage:timage; source:trect; dest:trect);
var
copyBmp,pasteBmp: TBitmap;
begin
if (Cimage.Picture.Graphic <> nil) and not Cimage.Picture.Graphic.Empty then
  begin
  copyBmp:=TBitmap.Create;
  pasteBmp:=TBitmap.Create;
    try
    copyBmp.Height:=Cimage.Height;
    copyBmp.Width:=Cimage.Width;
    pasteBmp.Height:=source.Height;
    pasteBmp.Width:=source.Width;
    copyBmp.canvas.Draw(0, 0, Cimage.Picture.Graphic);
    pasteBmp.Canvas.CopyRect(rect(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), copyBmp.Canvas, source);
    FOD_canvas:=pasteBmp.Canvas;
    finally
    copyBmp.free;
    pasteBmp.free;
    end;
  Fdrawing_rect:=dest;
  Fowner_draw:=true;
  invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

Why is this happening? I tried googling and the Delphi help.

Comment: What is CImage? Is it also a TBitmap. Which line of code causes the failure?

Comment: cimage is any timage object,   copyBmp.canvas.Draw(0,0,Cimage.Picture.Graphic); if you notice i use the graphic to draw

Comment: this line causes the failure canvas.CopyRect(ClientRect,FOD_canvas,ClientRect);

Comment: You kept a reference to the canvas of `pasteBmp`, and then promptly destroyed `pasteBmp`. What did you expect would happen when you used the canvas of a destroyed bitmap. Solution is going to involve fixing code that you have not shown.

Comment: If you're using F8 to step through your code then it will fail on canvas.copyrect, when you reach that line press F7 to step through the procedure one line at a time. It will give you a better idea of which line. David is right, you are freeing the objects and then using them. Here's a tip "David is always right" :)

Comment: so you mean that when i use FOD_canvas:=pasteBmp.Canvas; the info in pasteBmp.canvas is passed to the FOD_canvas field as a reference not as a value?

Comment: Correct. And that reference because invalid as soon as you destroy the bitmap. Instead of remembering the canvas, you should remember the bitmap, I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, the error is because you are keeping a reference to a destroyed `TCanvas` and then trying to draw with it.  You need to keep a copy of the actual `TBitmap` instead and then you can draw with it when needed:

```
constructor Tncrtile.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FOD_Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
end;

destructor Tncrtile.Destroy;
begin
  FOD_Bmp.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure Tncrtile.copy_rect(Cimage: TImage; Source, Dest: TRect);
var
  copyBmp, pasteBmp: TBitmap;
begin
  if (Cimage.Picture.Graphic <> nil) and (not Cimage.Picture.Graphic.Empty) then
  begin
    copyBmp := TBitmap.Create;
    pasteBmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      copyBmp.Height := Cimage.Height;
      copyBmp.Width := Cimage.Width;
      pasteBmp.Height := Source.Height;
      pasteBmp.Width := Source.Width;
      copyBmp.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Cimage.Picture.Graphic);    
      pasteBmp.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, Source.Width, Source.Height), copyBmp.Canvas, Source);
      FOD_Bmp.Assign(pasteBmp);
    finally
      copyBmp.Free;
      pasteBmp.Free;
    end;
    Fdrawing_rect := Dest;
    Fowner_draw := True;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

...

```
if Fowner_draw and (not FOD_BMP.Empty) then
begin
  Canvas.CopyRect(ClientRect, FOD_Bmp.Canvas, ClientRect);
end
```